# Change color of circle button when clicked in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, button

I have this XAML code for a button. I need this button to just be a circle of a solid color.

```
<Button x:Name="btn_Color" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Black"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

I want this button to change color when I click it, and be able to reuse this code for other buttons. I will use the color later for other things so I need to be able to access that data.
I tried to add a PreviewMouseDown event to the Ellipse and change the property on `(Ellipse)sender` but I can't access the color of the Ellipse even if I add it a `x:Name` property. How can I achieve this? Thanks! :)

Comment: you could make something like: `<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />` and then, in your code you could call `((Button)sender).Foreground = Brushes.Black;`

Comment: If you want to reuse it, you could make this as Style for button and use it like `<Button Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource YourButtonStyle}"/>`
Also, in style you could use triggers like `<Trigger Property="Pressed" Value="True"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>`

Comment: @sTrenat - Please write it as an answer instead of a comment. Comments are hard to find and read.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd It's just suggestion, not full solution. First, I would need to know more details from TheBosco before answering.

Comment: @sTrenat - Then, instead of commenting a guess, ask for clarification. That is what the comments are for. It's great that you want to help, and to make your contribution as valuable as possible, answers should be easy to find and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve what you want. It is at least a starting point:

```
  <Button x:Name="btn_Color" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Doing it this way, you can then Bind the BorderBrush to a different color, or a DependencyProperty and change it from another place.

Comment: I made a few changes to this code and achieved what I wanted. Thank you!